# UpdateInstallationWizard.aspx and/or sitecore.ship isn't working

Tags: packages, sitecore-ship

Stood up the 8.2 Update 1 environment. However I'm getting the error below when trying to install the update package generated by TDS. Works fine locally but not in Azure Web Apps.

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: control

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: control

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: control]
   System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackEventReference(Control control, String argument, Boolean forUrl, Boolean registerForEventValidation) +2866706
   Sitecore.Update.Wizard.ProcessUpdatePackage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +131
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +131
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +131
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +678
```

And when I try to install update packages via sitecore.ship curl.exe I get below:

> curl.exe -i --connect-timeout 300 --max-time 1200 --insecure
>   --show-error --silent --form "path=@E:\agent_work\37\b_Packages\mypackage.Master.update"
>   https://mysite/services/package/install/fileupload

```
<body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>Value cannot be null.<br>Parameter name: path</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for mo
re information about the error and where it originated in the code.

            <br><br>

            <b> Exception Details: </b>System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.<br>Parameter name: path<br><br>

            <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code>

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception c
an be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path]
   System.IO.File.Delete(String path) +12218112
   Sitecore.Ship.Infrastructure.IO.TempPackager.Dispose() +7
   Sitecore.Ship.AspNet.Package.InstallUploadPackageCommand.HandleRequest(HttpContextBase context) +307
   Sitecore.Ship.AspNet.Package.InstallPackageCommand.HandleRequest(HttpContextBase context) +258
   Sitecore.Ship.AspNet.AboutCommand.HandleRequest(HttpContextBase context) +197
   Sitecore.Ship.AspNet.SitecoreShipHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase context) +13
   Sitecore.Ship.AspNet.BaseHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +176
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +188
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously) +69
</pre></code>
```

**UPDATE:**

Found the culprit:

```
<sc.variable name="tempFolder" value="d:\local\temp"/>
```

When I change to `<sc.variable name="tempFolder" value="/temp"/>`

Note sure whether this fix is good/bad. I think sitecore's solution to web app common file share issue is to store media cache / submit queue etc to d:\local.

Any idea?

Comment: not 100% sure but for me it looks like either d:\local\temp did not exist or there were not sufficient permissions for Network Service \ IUSR to that folder

Comment: @markcassidy how is this question off the topic?